# Power BI: The key didn't match any rows in the table

Tags: powerbi

I want to update imported data from SQL database in Power BI.

In data transformation/modelling, I changed the SQL Statement to:

```
select *
from my_table
where month_column = MONTH(getdate())
and year_column = YEAR(getdate())
```

This worked in the Power Query Editor(as well as in SQL server) but as I selected `Close & Apply` it caught error:

[image]

Tried:

According to [Chris' article](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2020/04/06/understanding-the-the-key-didnt-match-any-rows-in-the-table-error-in-power-query-in-power-bi-or-excel/), it might be that something has been deleted or been renamed in my data source, but I checked all the column names are the same.

A [Power BI community answer](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Expression-Error-The-key-didn-t-match-any-rows-in-the-table/m-p/155986) suggested potential cause due to credentials, also checked and there was no problem with that.

Also, I tried to close SQL and rerun the SQL Statement in Power BI but it didn't help.

Lastly, I came across [this Power BI community answer](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Expression-Error-The-key-didn-t-match-any-rows-in-the-table/m-p/155986):
[image]

Although it's about Excel, it shares the similar idea as [Chris' article](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2020/04/06/understanding-the-the-key-didnt-match-any-rows-in-the-table-error-in-power-query-in-power-bi-or-excel/). I have created and added columns after importing the data from SQL, which then exist in my current table but not in the SQL data I'm trying to import, can this be the reason? Or is it a Power BI internal connection glitch, given that the SQL Statement actually worked in the SQL Server and Power BI data modelling ?

Comment: It is a mismatch between the metadata in power query and the sql columns. Don't do select *, specify the columns

Comment: Hi @Jon I tried specifying the individual column names but it seems the issue remains.